# Qt Creator exited with code -1073741819

Tags: qt, dll, path, qt-creator

When trying to run a debug version of my app in Qt 5.1.1 I'm getting:

```
Starting C:\Users\Jared\Documents\Telkonet\serial_loader\branches\2.x\build-esu-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\esu.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\Users\Jared\Documents\Telkonet\serial_loader\branches\2.x\build-esu-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\esu.exe exited with code -1073741819
```

An ldd of the exe file shows:

```
$ ldd build-esu-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug/esu.exe
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7fed5810000)
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x77b00000)
        wow64.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/wow64.dll (0x77a40000)
        wow64win.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/wow64win.dll (0x77aa0000)
        wow64cpu.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/wow64cpu.dll (0x77a90000)
        ??? => ??? (0x2b0000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x76b80000)
        ??? => ??? (0x2b0000)
        ??? => ??? (0x2b0000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x76b80000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x76ad0000)
```

My Path variable includes:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\mingw48_32\lib\;
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\;
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\mingw48_32\bin\;
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\;
```

It is also worth noting that I have just installed Qt 5.1.1 after uninstalling Qt 4.8.4.

Update:

I went through all my source code and replaced all instances of Q_WS_WIN with Q_OS_WIN. Now I am getting this:

```
Starting C:\Users\Jared\Documents\Telkonet\serial_loader\branches\2.x\debug\debug\esu.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\Users\Jared\Documents\Telkonet\serial_loader\branches\2.x\debug\debug\esu.exe exited with code -1073741515
```

After putting the required dlls in the debug folder, I get error code 1073741819 again. Main() is still not being reached.

Comment: Confusing title: Not QtCreator but esu.exe exited :); Is esu's main() function reached when you set a breakpoint in the first line?; are you mixing cygwin with non-cygwin-based Qt or something?

Comment: The qDebug() I put in the first line of main() is not showing in application output. It looks like the main() method is not being reached. As for cygwin, I only used that to do an ldd.

Answer (score 0):

After much poking around, I discovered it was an issue with the boost library version I was using. I downloaded and installed the latest boost library version. It is now working.